# Export C# Encog Neuronal Network to C++

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, encog

I have used the Encog C# framework to create a neural network. The neural network is fully trained. So I would like to use the neural network in my main application to solve a subproblem.

Is there a way to export the neural network into my main application which is written in C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have such wish, then most straightforward way would be to convert C# code to C++ by yourself. That way actually isn't practical or achievable easy. So I propose you another way. From your C++ app use encog as .Net assembly. There are plenty of articles which explain how to [call .Net assembly from C++.](https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c%2B%2B%20call%20.net%20library&*)